# How to properly track playback position? [Android Media Broadcast Notifications Spotify API]

Tags: android, api, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, spotify

After reading the documentation on Spotify's Android Media Notifications API, https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/android-sdk/guides/android-media-notifications/, I successfully managed to receive the notifications metadata and it is displayed properly on my app.

However, the notifications metadata is only updated when the queue changes, when the track changes, and when playback is changed, so unless one of these three actions happens, the "positionInMs" intent extra isn't sent.

As of right now as a workaround I am simply starting a timer using the time the intent was sent, the last known playback position, and the track duration to track current playback position.

This seemed to work at first, but after further testing I've realized that the timer I set can go out of sync, if the track the user is listening to freezes because of a slow internet connection.

Any ideas to properly track the playback position, while accounting for a slow internet connection? Or are there any alternatives I should look into?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this question is rather old, but I am going to answer anyway if anyone else comes across it.

I recommend constantly querying Spotify to get the playback position. One way you can do this is by using a timer and querying Spotify every given time frame. The below example queries Spotify every 100ms. If you want to reduce/increase the numbers of queries, you can simply use stopwatch.setClockDelay() and provide your required time

For instance, you can use this timer library

```
    implementation 'com.yashovardhan99.timeit:timeit:1.2.0'
```

Then use the following code:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spotify);

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.setOnTickListener(this);
    stopwatch.start();

   }

    @Override
    public void onTick(Stopwatch stopwatch) {
    Data.getAndroidSpotifyAppRemote().getPlayerApi().getPlayerState().setResultCallback(new CallResult.ResultCallback<PlayerState>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlayerState playerState) {
           Log.d("TAG", playerState.playbackPosition);
        }
    });

}
```

Don't forget to add the following code at the top of your class:

```
implements Stopwatch.OnTickListener
```